# How cross join two tables in SQL Server, repeating only some values

Tags: sql-server, join

In SQL Server, I have two tables. First one is as follows:

```
id Value
1  Green
2  Yellow
3  Red
```

The second one is

```
id Value
1  John
2  Paul
3  George
4  Ringo
5  Mick
6  Keith
7  Ronnie
```

How can I join these two tables, such as the result dataset it's as follows:

```
id1 Value1 id2 Value2
1   Green  1   John
2   Yellow 2   Paul
3   Red    3   George
1   Green  4   Ringo
2   Yellow 5   Mick
3   Red    6   Keith
1   Green  7   Ronnie
```

Comment: I changed the number of rows in each example table to an odd number of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select *
From (Select
  t.*,
  2 - (Row_number() over (order by id) % 2) idx
From second_table t) t inner join first_table t2 on t2.id = t.idx;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a statement in the where clause
saying that table1.id % 2 = table2.id % 2

The modulo operator % will match odd values of the second table to green and even values to yellow.

Comment: Thak you, great answer; what if I have 3 rows in the first table and 7 in the second?

Comment: @thx0125:  If you have 3 rows in the first and 7 in the second, then use a % 3 instead of a % 2.  The first 6 rows in the second table will match up with the first table as expected.  The 7th row in the second table will match the 1st row of the first table such that there will be 3 occurrences of the first table - first row, and only 2 occurrences of the first table's second and third rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one sample that should work with the updated version of the question:

```
declare @colors table (
    id int not null,
    value nvarchar(15) not null
)
declare @people table (
    id int not null,
    name nvarchar(15) not null
)

insert into @colors (id, value) values (1, 'Green'),(2,'Yellow'),(3,'Red')
insert into @people (id, name) values (1, 'John'),(2,'Paul'),(3,'George'),(4,'Ringo'),(5,'Mick'),(6,'Keith'),(7,'Ronnie')

----

select csub.id, csub.value, psub.id, psub.name
from 
    (
        select id, name, 
            (row_number() over (order by id)) % (select count(*) from @colors) as rnum
        from @people
    ) as psub
    join (
        select id, value, 
            ((row_number() over (order by id)) % (select count(*) from @colors)) as rnum
        from @colors
    ) csub on psub.rnum = csub.rnum
order by psub.id
```

Note: This also works even if the actual ID values in either table has gaps. Like:

```
insert into @colors (id, value) values (1, 'Green'),(17,'Yellow'),(33,'Red'),(47,'Black)
insert into @people (id, name) values (1, 'John'),(2,'Paul'),(3,'George'),(7,'Ringo'),(15,'Mick'),(16,'Keith'),(37,'Ronnie')
```

And it works regardless of how many rows you have in the colors table. Output using sample above, with gaps in ID ranges:

```
+----+--------+----+--------+
| id | value  | id |  name  |
+----+--------+----+--------+
|  1 | Green  |  1 | John   |
| 17 | Yellow |  2 | Paul   |
| 33 | Red    |  3 | George |
| 47 | Black  |  7 | Ringo  |
|  1 | Green  | 15 | Mick   |
| 17 | Yellow | 16 | Keith  |
| 33 | Red    | 37 | Ronnie |
+----+--------+----+--------+
```